# Solve an equation; Ax=b regarding matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I'm studying to linear algebra in community college, and I'm having a hard time with this exercise because I don't really understand what we are doing.

We have a 3x3 matrix *A*, and we know that the eigenspaces of that matrix are *E(1,A)=Sp(v1,v2)*  and *E(2,A)=Sp(v3)* where v1=(1,0,1) v2=(0,1,0) and v3=(1,0,-1).

Then we are supposed to solve an equation of the form *Ax=b* where b is a vector *b=3,4,5*.

Am I supposed to create a matrix out of the v1,v2,v3 vectors and then somehow solve x from that? Also i dont know what matrix A is, We just assume to know its eigenspaces (and values), could I solve what matrix A is from the eigenspaces (I dont know how to do that lol).

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated, since I don't really know what steps to take and where.

Comment: Have you heard about *diagonalizable matrices*?

Comment: No I haven't, would the be important in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, it would trivialize the process.  You'd learn that $A$ is [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) as $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$, built from the eigenvectors and eigenvalues.  At this point you can use whatever traditional methods you are most comfortable with, e.g. inverting the matrix.

Comment: Okay thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that, from your problem statement:

$$Av_1 = v_1 \,\,\text{  and  }\,\, A v_2 = v_2 \,\, \text{  and  }\,\,  Av_3 = 2v_3.$$

Also, it should be clear that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$ so

$$b= c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3$$ for some $c_1,c_2,c_3$ not all zero.

Find the $c_j$'s .  Then

$$Ab = A(c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3 v_3)= c_1 Av_1 + c_2 Av_2 + c_3 Av_3=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+ 2c_3 v_3.$$